# KeyRemap4MacBook Meta + KEY Repeat Question

Tags: macos, keyboard, emacs

I come from a Linux/PC world as a heavy Emacs user and for the last year, I've "dealt" with the standard OS X key remapping. It's OK, but the things that bother me are:

- Option + Key doesn't operate as Meta by default (though works inside Emacs), instead it operates as a compose key.
- Control-C/Control-V are not true cut-n-paste
- Why the hell did the Function key have to be where the Control-L key should be?

I spent some time yesterday with [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook) and [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) and came up with a general approximation of what I want.

*PCKeyboardHack - Swap CapsLock*

- Select Caps Lock->Change Caps Lock
- Enter keycode 63 (for Fn key)

*KeyRemap4MacBook - Move things around*

- Command_L to Escape
- Command_R to Escape
- ControL to Fn
- Fn to Control_L (+ Option-L+Fn to Fn)
- Option_L to Command_L
- Option_R to Control_R
- Use PC Style Copy/Paste

The only thing that remains "broken" is the use of Option_L or Option_R as a pressed meta-key and another key on the keyboard. Meta-F and Meta-B are commonly used Emacs keybindings for hopping forward and backwards between words. With the configuration above, I must release the Option key to affect Meta again. I've tried to play around with the Key Repeat settings, but haven't come up with a solution using the KR4MB UI. Any suggestions? Am I going to have to abandon this pursuit altogether?